# Eclipse PHP formatter for CakePHP

Tags: eclipse, cakephp, formatter, convention

In Eclipse

In Window->Preferences->PHP->Code Style->Formatter

I want to import for **CakePHP** instead of **PHP** but I haven't find in the file in format **XML**.

[image]

I appreciate you in advanced.

It should be a xml file like this:

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html

CakePHP encourages you to code using PSR-2, and it should be already included in Eclipse. Additionally, CakePHP ships with `.editorconfig` file, which, depending on your IDE setup, can be included and can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [editorconfig_plugin_Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/editorconfig-eclipse) to look for the Eclipse plugin.

Go to [editorconfig_demo](https://treyhunner.com/editorconfig-slides/#demo) for a brief demo slideshow which you could find informative.

Go to [editorconfig_example](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/.editorconfig) for an example CakePHP editorconfig file on GitHub.

Go to [editorconfig_tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbHw1VdjWbA) for a video tutorial (in 3 parts) on the editorconfig file which you could also find helpful.

That all being said, I think the Eclipse community is still waiting for a CakePHP formatting file that meets your needs, one that can just be dropped into the Eclipse environment.